# How to do the asp.net MVC equivalent of a button click like with JavaScript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

How can I for example have a button in a 'Create' view and when I click this button it calls a method in the associated controller?

My attempts so far have just resulted in sending me to a new page, e.g:

Create View

```
@Html.ActionLink("Get Tag", "getTag")
```

Controller

```
        public void getTag()
        {
            // Do something
            var x = 1;
            var z = 2;
            var e = x + z;
        }
```

Ultimately, I plan on getting the TagId from the option that is selected when the button is clicked and storing this.

```
    <select>
        @*Iterating Tag ViewModel *@
        @foreach (var item in Model.allTags)
        {
            <option value="item.TagId">@item.Name</option>

        }
    </select>
```

Most importantly, where can I learn about this specific type of stuff?

Thank you

Comment: You don't generally have button clicks that directly call server side code, at least you don't think of it that way. Your button click might invoke some JavaScript, which in turns makes an HTTP request to the server, which might respond with some structured data (ex: JSON). Do you know how to make an HTTP request from JavaScript? Do you know how to return JSON data from a controller in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

In general, to call a method on your controller directly from the view without JavaScript, you could do:

```
Html.ActionLink("Create", // Button Title
                "GetTag",   // <-- ActionMethod
                "Tag")  // <-- Controller Name
```

Your controller should contain an Action method like so:

```
public ActionResult GetTag()
{
     // Do something
     var x = 1;
     var z = 2;
     var e = x + z;

     return View();
}
```

In some cases, this doesn't suffice and you will need some JavaScript/jQuery to make an ajax call to your controller and return JSON data using "Json()" instead of "View()" on the return for example.

Also, you could use a different approach for your dropdown instead of a for loop. For example:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Tag.Id, new SelectList(Model.allTags, "TagId", "TagName"), "Select Tag", new { @class = "form-control" })
```